# JavaScript: Duplicate data property in object literal not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angular

**problem Description**

I am dealing with an optional variable called `ByteRange`. For this purpose I added 2 different URLs in `$resource`.

When I did that I got the following error:

```
Message:
    Error in parsing: "tools/test/retrieve/retrieve.service.js", Line 24: Duplicate data property in object literal not allowed in strict mode
Details:
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: true
```

I understood that I can't have 2 gets. Is there another way to deal with optional variables in Javascript?

---

**source code**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .factory('retrieve', retrieveObject);

    retrieveObject.$inject = ['$resource'];


    function retrieveObject($resource) {
        this.resource = $resource('api/tools/test', {}, {
            'list': {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/tools/test/list/:chain/:path/:dataCenter'
            },
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/tools/test/get/:chain/:dataCenter/:path/:byteRange'
            },
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/tools/test/get/:chain/:dataCenter/:path'
            },
        });

        return this;
    }

})();
```

Comment: Maybe deal with this variable :byteRange later in the code, I mean you must have a function that use this "get" which can (or not) take a parameter byteRange , in this function you can use "/:byteRange" or delete it depending of the byteRange  parameter

Comment: How can I add that condition. Very Interesting

Comment: I will add an answer with code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this is not perfect but it must help you, probably use regex instead of replace is a better idea.

```
function resolveUrl(url, params) {
    let resolvedUrl = url;

    for(let i in params) {
        resolvedUrl = resolvedUrl.replace(i, params[i]);
    }

    return resolvedUrl;
}

let params = {
    ':chain': 'aaa',
    ':dataCenter': 'bbb',
    ':path': 'ccc',
    ':byteRange': '',
};

let result = resolveUrl('api/tools/test/get/:chain/:dataCenter/:path/:byteRange', params);
console.log(result);
// Output : "api/tools/test/get/aaa/bbb/ccc/"

params = {
    ':chain': 'aaa',
    ':dataCenter': 'bbb',
    ':path': 'ccc',
    ':byteRange': 'yyy',
};

result = resolveUrl('api/tools/test/get/:chain/:dataCenter/:path/:byteRange', params);
console.log(result);
// Output : "api/tools/test/get/aaa/bbb/ccc/yyy"
```